# How to display the best fit equation (in text form) on plot when using numpy.polyfit?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

For the following example code, how can one display the best-fit equation on the plot?

```
x = np.arange(10)
y = 5 * x + 10

plt.plot(x, y, '.')
plt.plot(np.unique(x), np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 1))(np.unique(x)), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your code seems to work well, although a linear input function will not look very interesting. You might want to try `y = 5 * x + 10 + np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)` or so. Also, `np.unique` can be left out if it is know that all x's already are different.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I want to know how I can display the equation on my plot. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: I'd like to show y=5x+10 as a text on the plot

Comment: `plt.title('$y=5x+10$')` ?  or `plt.text(5, 30, '$y=5x+10$')` or ...?

Comment: I'd like in the area where the data is plotted. Ideally, near the plotted best-fit line. plt.txt(5, 30, '$y=5x+10$') did not allow my cell in Jupyter Lab to run...

Comment: Well, it really should run if you put everything in the same cell